# Extension that notifies new questions in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, support

Is there a browser extension (for Chrome), that gives an alert on new questions for predefined tags in Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[StackNotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/4400/stack-notifier-a-chrome-extension-to-show-new-questions-and-inbox-notification)

> Using stack notifier you can subscribe for set of tags in
>   Stackoverflow and also get real time notification from StackExchange
>   inbox.